# Generic type on class for API

Tags: c#

I have a class like this:

```
public class Header
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DateTypeColumn { get; set; }
}
```

There a way to change the type **string** of **DataTypeColumn** to one where the user can submit what type the column will be.

Something like this:

Name: ExampleColumnInt

DataTypeColumn: int -> this is the type int, not a string, so I need some type more generic in the prop DataTypeColumn

So when I recive this on an API I can convert the data of a object to that type.

Comment: You say "There a way to change the type string of DataTypeColumn to one where the user can submit what type the column will be.". Do you mean that the user can submit anything to your API? Or do you know before hand what is the user going to submit?

Answer (score 6):

```
public class Header<T> 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T DateTypeColumn { get; set; }
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: But I can use type T to send data on JSON for an API?

Comment: @iMSn20 -- yes -- as long as when you deserialze you use the same type for `T` as what was used when it was serialized.

Comment: @iMSn20 at runtime T is replaced by the real type. I can't speak for how t a particular serializer will handle a generic class. I've done this in the past with JSON.Net.

Comment: This is not likely to work, specifically because of deserialization. You need to know to what T to deserialize to and if that's known only at runtime, you need a way to identify it first

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I think I confused C# generics with Java's. C# resolves the generic types at compile time. This does work.